# Can I have a deferrable unique functional index in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, indexing, unique, ora-00904

I'd like to create a deferrable unique functional index in Oracle 10g.

I know how to create a unique functional index:

```
create unique index LIST_ITEM_ENTRY_NO_UNIQ
on LIST_ITEM (case status when 'cancel' then null else LIST_KEY end,
              case status when 'cancel' then null else ENTRY_NO end);
```

I know how to create a deferrable unique index:

```
alter table LIST_ITEM add constraint LIST_ITEM_ENTRY_NO_UNIQ
unique (LIST_KEY,ENTRY_NO) deferrable initially deferred;
```

Knowing these two things, I tried this:

```
alter table LIST_ITEM add constraint LIST_ITEM_ENTRY_NO_UNIQ
unique (case STATUS when 'cancel' then null else LIST_KEY end,
        case STATUS when 'cancel' then null else ENTRY_NO end)
deferrable initially deferred;
```

But I get an "ORA-00904 : invalid identifier" error. Either I've got the syntax wrong, or perhaps Oracle doesn't support deferrable functional indices? Could someone provide me with a solution or else a definitive answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice try, but according to the Oracle 10g Documentation, the syntax for CREATE INDEX and ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT are not interchangeable in this regard, which is why you got that syntax error:

```
CREATE INDEX ::=

    CREATE [ UNIQUE | BITMAP ] INDEX [ schema. ]index
      ON { cluster_index_clause
         | table_index_clause
         | bitmap_join_index_clause
         } ;

table_index_clause ::=

    [ schema. ]table [ t_alias ]
    (index_expr [ ASC | DESC ]
      [, index_expr [ ASC | DESC ] ]...)
    [ index_properties ]

index_expr ::= { column | column_expression }
```

Therefore CREATE INDEX allows column_expression, which is basically a "function-based index".

On the other hand:

```
ALTER TABLE ::=
ALTER TABLE [ schema. ]table
  [ alter_table_properties
  | column_clauses
  | constraint_clauses
  | alter_table_partitioning
  | alter_external_table_clauses
  | move_table_clause
  ]
  [ enable_disable_clause
  | { ENABLE | DISABLE }
    { TABLE LOCK | ALL TRIGGERS }
    [ enable_disable_clause
    | { ENABLE | DISABLE }
      { TABLE LOCK | ALL TRIGGERS }
    ]...
  ] ;

constraint_clauses ::=
{ ADD { out_of_line_constraint
        [ out_of_line_constraint ]...
      | out_of_line_REF_constraint
      }
| MODIFY { CONSTRAINT constraint
         | PRIMARY KEY
         | UNIQUE (column [, column ]...)
         }
         constraint_state
| RENAME CONSTRAINT old_name TO new_name
| drop_constraint_clause
}

out_of_line_constraint ::=
[ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ]
{ UNIQUE (column [, column ]...)
| PRIMARY KEY (column [, column ]...)
| FOREIGN KEY (column [, column ]...)
     references_clause
| CHECK (condition)
}
[ constraint_state ]
```

Therefore a UNIQUE constraint definition may only be column names, and cannot be column expressions.

You can do this in 11g using virtual columns, in 10g and earlier most people tend to create derived columns (along with the burden of keeping them up-to-date programmatically).

Comment: Well, I asked for a definitive answer, and apparently this is it, even if it is not the one I was hoping for. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the 11g [virtual columns](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm#sthref7275) functionality. You'd create the function as a virtual column, then add the cosntraint on that.

Comment: I don't have ready access to an 11g installation. Can someone confirm Gary's solution?

I noticed this statement in the Language Reference linked above: "A table index defined on a virtual column is equivalent to a function-based index on the table."

If indeed there is a solution using 11g virtual columns, then perhaps there is an equivalent solution without them?

Answer (score -2):

[Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1500734400346690148) addresses this issue. The answer is no, you can't create unique constraints based upon functional indexes.

Comment: The linked "Ask Tom" article appears to be only tangentially related to the question here. The user in the article asks how to create a "selectively unique" index with novalidate, to which the response is basically "Why use novalidate? Just make your index even more selective to get what you want." The response does not clearly indicate whether or not it is actually possible to have a functional index with NOVALIDATE, and does not even mention making an index deferrable.

Comment: You clearly *can* create unique constraints based on functional indexes. The question is how to make them deferrable.